# Enabling "Connect to Outlook" in a regular list in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-on-prem

Is it possible to enable the connect to outlook option in a regular list in SharePoint?

I already have a list with lot of columns and we need the Connect to outlook option enabled.

Is there a way to do it? or should I create a new calendar list and copy all the columns to it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this with a Calendar view. SharePoint enables/disables the Connect to Outlook button based on the list type.